# Como resolver una excepción de "Tiempo de espera para la operación de espera agotado"

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-server, xampp

Estoy intentando hacer una conexión entre SQL server y laravel con xampp, después de hacer todo lo correspondiente en el xampp, como las extensiones de SQL server y demás componentes necesarios, lo testeo con la configuración de mi base de datos y me dice que la conexión es exitosa, por lo cual se conecta a la misma, pero al momento de hacer cualquier operación, ya sea consulta o escritura en la BD me salta esta excepción:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: 
>   Tiempo de espera de la operación de espera agotado.

¿Alguna idea de como modificar el valor del tiempo para la excepción o alguna otra forma de resolver el problema?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Sabes si el usuario que utilizas tiene permisos de lectura y/o escritura?

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos tu archivo .env?

Comment: El usuario tiene todos los permisos, y el archivo .env contiene modificado esto, lo demás esta como viene por defecto:

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=SRVFVISQL07\FVIMOIPRO01
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=prueba
DB_USERNAME=prueba
DB_PASSWORD=prueba

Answer (score 0):

Este mismo error me surgio a mi, intente modificar el max_execution_time pero nada de esto resulto hasta que despues de mucho buscar y probar el problema era el puerto configurado en mi .env para sql server te puede servir cualquiera de estas 2 configuraciones

1.

```
DB_PORT=1433
```

2. DB_PORT=56011

Espero que esto les sirva; a mi me funciono.